# Order of @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle all my app exceptions :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

  @ExceptionHandler({UnauthorizedException.class})
  public String unauthorizedException()  {
        .........
  }


  @ExceptionHandler({UnauthorizedAjaxException.class})
  @ResponseBody
  public void unauthorizedAjaxException()  {
        .........
  }

  @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
  public String globalException(){
        .........
  }


}
```

And somewhere in my code i do `throw new UnauthorizedException();`

```
   @Around("@annotation(Authenticated)")
   public Object profilingAuthentication(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable  {

       HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

       if( request.getSession().getAttribute("idContact") == null ) {
            if( "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With")) )
                throw new UnauthorizedAjaxException();
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
       } 
       return pjp.proceed();
   }
```

But sadly Spring MVC appears to be acting random by using the most generic case (`Exception`) rather than more specific ones (`UnauthorizedException` for example). And sometimes he choose the correct one !

How the order works works ? and is there any way to specify the order ?

`UnauthorizedException` is a custom exception

```
public class UnauthorizedException extends Exception {

    public UnauthorizedException(){
        super();
    }

    public UnauthorizedException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

i found out that the order it's **not rondom** actually the methods who throw `UnauthorizedException` works normally but the others not !

```
@Authenticated
@RequestMapping(value="/favoris") 
public String favoris(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) 
      throws UnauthorizedException {
    ....
}

@Authenticated
@RequestMapping(value="/follow") 
public String follow(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    .....
}
```

So i have to add `throws UnauthorizedException` manually or there is some other solution ?

Comment: What does it mean when you say it does not work for methods which do not throw `UnauthorizedException`? As `UnauthorizedException` is a custom exception, you have to throw it, otherwise how is the application expected to throw it for you?

Answer (score 1):

we are using exception handler in following way and never order get mixed and it work as expected.
So it could be possible if you will use it as following example then it will solve your problems

### handler class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public boolean handle1(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("#####Global Exception###" + exc);
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return true;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
    public boolean handle2(CustomException exc) {
        System.out.println("###custom exception######" + exc);
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Controller class

```
@RestController("test")
@RequestMapping("/test1")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/t1")
    public boolean test() {
        if (true) {
            throw new CustomException();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In above example exception habdler is **handle2** because 1st of all it will search for matching exception if not found then go for parrent handler

If we throw new NullPointerException() then it will search for matching handler but not found in this case then go for parrent that is **handle1**

for more you can refer [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

I hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: Did someone validate this and can confirm? Any official sources?

Comment: As far as I can see, this is nonsense. Long story short: the most specific ExceptionHandler will be chosen. The actual algorithm has been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500823/193705

Answer (score 1):

Use an annotation **@Order** or implement an interface **Ordered** for **@ControllerAdvice**.

See implementations of:

- **ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver** class
- **ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver** class (method **initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache**)
- **AnnotationAwareOrderComparator** class

Answer (score 0):

There is no order/priority as long as you have a single controlleradvice class in your project. But if you have multiple controlleradvice classes, you can set the Order. But here, in your case, the order is not applicable as the two exceptions are handled differently (i.e., UnauthorizedException and Exception).

> The good thing is, Spring will automatically find the respective custom Exception class (if any,
>   otherwise generic Exception) and invoke the corresponding method.

Please refer for more information on Spring Controller Advice and Exception handling:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Are you suggesting they should have a single `@ExceptionHandler` for their application?

Comment: I am NOT suggesting to have a single ExceptionHandler at all.

Comment: Can you clarify how _you can set the Order_? I think that's what they are asking.

Comment: But the order is not applicable as long as the exceptions are different.

Comment: With all your edits, it seems your answer boils down to _But here, in your case, the order is not applicable as the two exceptions are handled differently_. But they already know this through the behavior of their program. Are you saying there is no way to set that order? And how do you explain OP's claim that behavior sometimes alternates between handlers?

Comment: @developer i don't wanna use multiple controlleradvice classes

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis do you have some explaination ? i follow your approch up there http://stackoverflow.com/a/19302001/1383538