# NoSuchElementException @ExceptionHandler in Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring, exceptionhandler

I have created a custom exception handler in Spring Boot:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class DataApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
 @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
        public final void **handleNoSuchElementException**(NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.err.println("This is throwing :"+ex.getMessage());
        }
...
@ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> **handleAll**(final Exception ex) {
...
```

and it's throwing exception like

```
throw new NoSuchElementException("SomelogicalDescription");
```

but each time I throw this NoSuchElementException, handleAll is executed instead of handleNoSuchElementException.

I might be missing something very trivial. To change NoSuchElementException with NotFoundException does not make any difference.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498378/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers

Comment: No I haven't, I am doing that now. Thank you

Comment: Anyone looking for specific answer please go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462588/order-of-exceptionhandler

Comment: just  remove (just for verify) handleAll**() all then check if call comes to handleNoSuchElementException**()

Comment: This has been marked by the OP as being a duplicate of: [Order of @ExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462588/order-of-exceptionhandler)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you doesn't understand a `@RestControllerAdvice` activity:

> NOTE: @RestControllerAdvice is processed if an appropriate HandlerMapping-HandlerAdapter pair is configured such as the RequestMappingHandlerMapping-RequestMappingHandlerAdapter pair which are the default in the MVC Java config and the MVC namespace. [RestControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html)

Use `@ControllerAdvice` instead: [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

You have a `void` handler - why do you expect a response then?

What do you return there? It should be like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class InvalidValuesExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler({ InvalidValuesException.class })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidRequest(RuntimeException exc, WebRequest request) {
    InvalidValuesException ive = (InvalidValuesException) exc;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

    BasicResultMessage msg = new BasicResultMessage(ive.getDataId(),
                                                    ive.getMessage());
    SendDataResult result = new SendDataResult(false, msg);

    return handleExceptionInternal(exc, result, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in simple terms?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124391/restcontrolleradvice-vs-controlleradvice

Comment: I think you did not understand the question.Nowhere I asked for response.

Comment: @Rishi move `public final void` with `protected ResponseEntity<Object>`

Comment: did that ..still there. :(